# Making a tooltip-like easter egg

Tags: actionscript-3, tooltip

I'm trying to make an easter egg in my AS3 app, that appears when the user hovers their cursor over a seperate trigger, and disappears when they stop hovering over it.

```
var hideEast:Tween=new Tween(easter_mc,"alpha",null,100,0,1,false);
easterTrigger_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, triEas);
easterTrigger_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, remEas);
function triEas (e:MouseEvent):void{
    var showEast:Tween=new Tween(easter_mc,"alpha",null,0,100,1,false);
}

function remEas (e:MouseEvent):void{
    var hideEast;
}
```

This is the code I've tried to use. It shows the movie clip when the trigger is being hovered over, but the movie clip stays when the triggered isn't being hovered over anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have any animation in your MOUSE_OUT handler.
Also, I would recommend tweening engine from Jack Doyle - [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/v12/).

```
trigger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver, false, 0, true);
trigger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut, false, 0, true);

function onOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    TweenLite.to(trigger, 0.3, {alpha: 1, ease: Sine.easeOut});
}

function onOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    TweenLite.to(trigger, 0.5, {alpha: 0, ease: Sine.easeInOut});
}
```

Or you can go further and use visibility.

```
trigger.alpha = 0;
trigger.visible = false;

TweenPlugin.activate([AutoAlphaPlugin]);

trigger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver, false, 0, true);
trigger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut, false, 0, true);

function onOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    TweenLite.to(trigger, 0.3, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Sine.easeOut});
}

function onOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    TweenLite.to(trigger, 0.5, {autoAlpha: 0, ease: Sine.easeInOut});
}
```